# How to restart Jenkins on Windows?

Tags: jenkins

This is the first time I am using Jenkins. Manage Jenkins > Manage Plugins > Available tab > Maven selected > Downloading is done.

When I go to New item page, I still do not see Maven. I guess I need to restart Jenkins.

I tried `localhost:8080/reload`, `localhost:8080/restart`, and `http://localhost:8080/safeRestart`. I get error "Jenkins cannot restart itself as currently configured."

I still see command prompt is running.

[image]

In addition, I cd to jenkins folder and tried to restart from there but did not work.

```
jenkins.exe restart
2020-06-05 21:06:02,783 INFO  - Restarting the service with id 'jenkins'
2020-06-05 21:06:02,795 FATAL - WMI Operation failure: NoSuchService
WMI.WmiException: NoSuchService
   at winsw.WrapperService.ThrowNoSuchService()
   at winsw.WrapperService.Run(String[] _args, ServiceDescriptor descriptor)
   at winsw.WrapperService.Main(String[] args)
WMI.WmiException: NoSuchService
   at winsw.WrapperService.ThrowNoSuchService()
   at winsw.WrapperService.Run(String[] _args, ServiceDescriptor descriptor)
   at winsw.WrapperService.Main(String[] args)
```

How can I restart Jenkins on windows machine?

---

Update 1

I took the following steps at the beginning to install and launch jenkins.

https://updates.jenkins-ci.org/download/war/
Downloaded war file
Created a folder Jenkins in c drive and moved the downloaded war to the Jenkins folder

Opened command prompt
cd to the jenkins folder
java -jar Jenkins.war
It gave me temp password

localhost:8080
Pasted the password

Created an account. 
Downloaded maven plugin in Jenkins. 
I do not see Maven plugin listed in Jenkins. After that, I am not sure how to restart Jenkins. I will go thru the wiki guide to install it as a windows service. Is there way to fix it without installing it as a windows service?

---

Update 2

When I try to install is a windows service, I get this

"

```
Error
Installing a service
[.jenkins] $ "C:\Users\Owner PC\.jenkins\jenkins.exe" install
2020-06-06 12:44:30,771 INFO  - Installing the service with id 'jenkins'
2020-06-06 12:44:30,859 FATAL - WMI Operation failure: AccessDenied
WMI.WmiException: AccessDenied
   at WMI.WmiRoot.BaseHandler.CheckError(ManagementBaseObject result)
   at WMI.WmiRoot.ClassHandler.Invoke(Object proxy, MethodInfo method, Object[] args)
   at WMI.Win32ServicesProxy.Create(String , String , String , ServiceType , ErrorControl , StartMode , Boolean , String , String , String[] )
   at winsw.WrapperService.Run(String[] _args, ServiceDescriptor descriptor)
   at winsw.WrapperService.Main(String[] args)
WMI.WmiException: AccessDenied
   at WMI.WmiRoot.BaseHandler.CheckError(ManagementBaseObject result)
   at WMI.WmiRoot.ClassHandler.Invoke(Object proxy, MethodInfo method, Object[] args)
   at WMI.Win32ServicesProxy.Create(String , String , String , ServiceType , ErrorControl , StartMode , Boolean , String , String , String[] )
   at winsw.WrapperService.Run(String[] _args, ServiceDescriptor descriptor)
   at winsw.WrapperService.Main(String[] args)"
```

---

Update 3

I deleted everything from the jenkins folder.

Open command prompt as admin.

Ran this command java -java jenkins.war. Last few links of the command prompt:

```
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
2020-06-06 18:53:28.976+0000 [id=21]    INFO    jenkins.model.Jenkins#cleanUp: S
topping Jenkins
2020-06-06 18:53:29.106+0000 [id=21]    INFO    jenkins.model.Jenkins$18#onAttai
ned: Started termination
2020-06-06 18:53:29.107+0000 [id=21]    SEVERE  jenkins.model.Jenkins$18#onTaskF
ailed: Failed NioChannelSelector.cleanUp
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to inject class jenkins.slaves.NioCha
nnelSelector
        at hudson.init.TaskMethodFinder.lookUp(TaskMethodFinder.java:125)
        at hudson.init.TaskMethodFinder.invoke(TaskMethodFinder.java:105)
        at hudson.init.TaskMethodFinder$TaskImpl.run(TaskMethodFinder.java:175)
        at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor.runTask(Reactor.java:296)
        at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor$2.run(Reactor.java:214)
        at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor$Node.run(Reactor.java:117)
        at jenkins.model.Jenkins$17.execute(Jenkins.java:3495)
        at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor$Node.runIfPossible(Reactor.java:139)

        at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor$Node.run(Reactor.java:128)
        at jenkins.model.Jenkins$17.execute(Jenkins.java:3495)
        at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor$Node.runIfPossible(Reactor.java:139)

        at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor.execute(Reactor.java:276)
        at jenkins.model.Jenkins._cleanUpRunTerminators(Jenkins.java:3492)
        at jenkins.model.Jenkins.cleanUp(Jenkins.java:3417)
        at hudson.WebAppMain$3.run(WebAppMain.java:283)
2020-06-06 18:53:29.140+0000 [id=21]    SEVERE  jenkins.model.Jenkins$18#onTaskF
ailed: Failed IOHubProvider.cleanUp
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to inject class jenkins.slaves.IOHubP
rovider
        at hudson.init.TaskMethodFinder.lookUp(TaskMethodFinder.java:125)
        at hudson.init.TaskMethodFinder.invoke(TaskMethodFinder.java:105)
        at hudson.init.TaskMethodFinder$TaskImpl.run(TaskMethodFinder.java:175)
        at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor.runTask(Reactor.java:296)
        at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor$2.run(Reactor.java:214)
        at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor$Node.run(Reactor.java:117)
        at jenkins.model.Jenkins$17.execute(Jenkins.java:3495)
        at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor$Node.runIfPossible(Reactor.java:139)

        at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor$Node.run(Reactor.java:128)
        at jenkins.model.Jenkins$17.execute(Jenkins.java:3495)
        at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor$Node.runIfPossible(Reactor.java:139)

        at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor.execute(Reactor.java:276)
        at jenkins.model.Jenkins._cleanUpRunTerminators(Jenkins.java:3492)
        at jenkins.model.Jenkins.cleanUp(Jenkins.java:3417)
        at hudson.WebAppMain$3.run(WebAppMain.java:283)
2020-06-06 18:53:29.143+0000 [id=21]    INFO    jenkins.model.Jenkins$18#onAttai
ned: Completed termination
2020-06-06 18:53:29.143+0000 [id=21]    INFO    jenkins.model.Jenkins#_cleanUpDi
sconnectComputers: Starting node disconnection
2020-06-06 18:53:29.148+0000 [id=21]    INFO    jenkins.model.Jenkins#_cleanUpSh
utdownPluginManager: Stopping plugin manager
2020-06-06 18:53:29.309+0000 [id=21]    INFO    c.b.j.cascade.PluginActivator#st
op: ### Stop.
2020-06-06 18:53:29.311+0000 [id=21]    INFO    jenkins.model.Jenkins#_cleanUpPe
rsistQueue: Persisting build queue
2020-06-06 18:53:29.385+0000 [id=21]    INFO    jenkins.model.Jenkins#cleanUp: J
enkins stopped
```

Comment: You don't mention how you launched Jenkins. If cmd line `java -jar jenkins.war`, you can't restart, just Ctrl-C or safeExit

Comment: Please see the update.

Answer (score 2):

The error log above gives some hint:

```
jenkins.exe restart
2020-06-05 21:06:02,783 INFO  - Restarting the service with id 'jenkins'
2020-06-05 21:06:02,795 FATAL - WMI Operation failure: NoSuchService
WMI.WmiException: NoSuchService
```

Since Jenkins is not installed as a Windows service, you are facing issue. First install it as a Windows service using the link provided below and then it should work. For that, go to `Manage Jenkins` section and there you will see an option `Install as Windows Service`. Once you will install Jenkins as a service, you will see a service with the name `jenkins` created as shown below:

[image]

https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Installing+Jenkins+as+a+Windows+service

Comment: @GreenTree: You have to open the command prompt in `Run as Administrator` mode

Comment: @GreenTree: Can you please paste the full log for `Update 3`? If it's too long, you may provide the link for GitHub Gist, Pastebin or something else. Also, what version of Jenkins are you using?

Comment: I wiped everything off and reinstalled jenkins using windows installer. I am now dealing with different issues. I will get back to you. Thank you!